# How to make celery retry using the same worker?

Tags: python, django, rabbitmq, celery

I'm just starting out with celery in a Django project, and am kinda stuck at this particular problem: Basically, I need to distribute a long-running task to different workers. The task is actually broken into several steps, each of which takes considerable time to complete. Therefore, if some step fails, I'd like celery to retry this task using the same worker to reuse the results from the completed steps. I understand that celery uses routing to distribute tasks to certain server, but I can't find anything about this particular problem. I use RabbitMQ as my broker.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could have every celeryd instance consume from a queue named after the hostname of the worker:

```
celeryd -l info -n worker1.example.com  -Q celery,worker1.example.com
```

sets the hostname to `worker1.example.com` and will consume from a queue named the same, as well as the default queue (named `celery`).

Then to direct a task to a specific worker you can use:

```
task.apply_async(args, kwargs, queue="worker1.example.com")
```

similary to direct a retry:

```
task.retry(queue="worker1.example.com")
```

or to direct the retry to the same worker:

```
task.retry(queue=task.request.hostname)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer! I think this is exactly what I'm looking for. I didn't realize that we can pass the queue name to retry(), but now it makes a lot of sense :)

Comment: Use `%computername%` on windows and `\`hostname\`` on linux to build the commandline.