# Local-only message queue?

Tags: rabbitmq, celery

I'm using Celery with RabbitMQ.

For my use case, I'll definitely have instances where I'll have messages which should be executed on any given node, but for one specific queue, I'll need things *only* executed on the originating server. This is because it works with a local-only file:

```
@celery.task
def calculate_hash(filename):
    target = Models.objects.get(filename=filename)
    hasher = hashlib.md5()
    with open(filename, "rb") as f:
        chunk = f.read(64 * 1024)
        while len(chunk) > 0:
            hasher.update(chunk)
            chunk = f.read(64 * 1024)
    target.hash = hasher.hexdigest()
    target.save()
```

Obviously, the above task is only relevant where `filename` actually exists, and it's not likely that it'll exist on multiple nodes at the same time.

Is there a way to specify that the given tasks only be executed locally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, if I'm correctly understanding your question, you should have one specific worker reading from one specific queue.

First of all, you can configure queues to work with on a `celeryd` level, e.g. by starting it with `--queues` option:

```
celeryd --queues=celery,queue1.mydomain.com
```

Then, to send a task to a specific queue, you can use [apply_async](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.app.task.html#celery.app.task.Task.apply_async) by setting `queue` argument.

Also see: [How to make celery retry using the same worker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8753216/how-to-make-celery-retry-using-the-same-worker)

Hope that helps.